# Crystal Report: Remove empty detail line in the last row of the page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report with Details section that has field that Can Grow to multiple lines. The Details section has vertical lines that span from the top of the section to the bottom. The problem is, in the last record on the page, sometimes it will display blank section, because the next record has 2 lines and it does not fit into the page. See below example.

[image: Report Preview]

How to resolve this problem? I tried checking/unchecking "Keep together" but it does not help.

Report Design view:

[image: Report Design View]

Horizontal line settings:

[image]

Vertical line settings:

[image]

Comment: show us your report desing plz

Comment: I've added the view.

Comment: If I were you, I would've extended thhis section till the very beginning of the PF.

Comment: Extending this section to beginning of the PF makes the last page has lines all the way to PF, even though the record does not fill in the whole page.

Comment: @rcs did you resolve this? because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you limit your columns in **details section** only. Do not extend to Report Footer.
Make the property of the *vertical* lines **ExtendToBottom** to **True**
Make the property of the *horizontal* lines **ExtendToBottom** to **True**

Comment: The columns are limited to details section. 
There is no report footer (Suppressed). 
The vertical lines has extend to bottom property to true and horizontal as well.
PageFooter is blank.

Comment: I just tried this solution and it seemed to work correctly, perhaps you have to giev it a try.

Comment: @Camahalan Royette, I am a crystal report novice (just started) and following this question for my learning. If possible, can you please elaborate or rephrase "limit your columns in details section only. Do not extend to Report Footer".

Comment: @MukulVarshney, the bottom end point of your columns must be inside the details section.